# make Mock.assert_called_with() agnostic to args vs kwargs

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Unit-tests should test functionality and try to be agnostic to implementation details.
`Mock.assert_called_with()` is a convenient function, yet AFAIK it compares `*args` to `*args` and `**kwargs` to `**kwargs`. Therefore:

```
# class to be mocked during test
class SomeClass():
    def func(self,a,b,c=5):
        # ...

# code under test
somaclass_instance.func(1,b=2,c=3)

# test code that works
someclass_mock.func.assert_called_with(1,b=2,c=3)

# test code that won't work
someclass_mock.func.assert_called_with(1,2,c=3)
someclass_mock.func.assert_called_with(a=1,b=2,c=3)
```

is there a way to generalize this so that the specifics of which `*args` where used as `**kwargs` in the call to `func`, which is really an implementation detail, will be ignored?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I understand your question, but you COULD pass *args and **kwargs in the same function call, or, since args are of type tuple, and kwargs are dicts, you might be able to write a wrapper function which normalizes the input to one that you're sure can work.

Comment: Is there any mock framework by now that does this? My tests shouldn't fail just because someone decided to change a positional argument into a keyword argument at some point. However, this question is the only time I've ever seen this issue mentioned. Mock already supports spec-objects, so this should be possible?

Answer (score 10):

Since Python 3.4, just like you wanted, asserting for specific call signatures is normalized automatically when a callable Mock is created with a spec, and for object methods when using auto-speccing.

From the very end of [the documentation of the Mock class](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class):

> A callable mock which was created with a spec (or a spec_set) will
>   introspect the specification object’s signature when matching calls to
>   the mock. Therefore, it can match the actual call’s arguments
>   regardless of whether they were passed positionally or by name:
>
> ```
> >>> def f(a, b, c): pass
> ...
> >>> mock = Mock(spec=f)
> >>> mock(1, 2, c=3)
> <Mock name='mock()' id='140161580456576'>
> >>> mock.assert_called_with(1, 2, 3)
> >>> mock.assert_called_with(a=1, b=2, c=3)
> ```
>
> This applies to assert_called_with(), assert_called_once_with(),
>   assert_has_calls() and assert_any_call(). When Autospeccing, it will
>   also apply to method calls on the mock object.
>
> Changed in version 3.4: Added signature introspection on specced and autospecced mock objects.

Answer (score 6):

File a feature request to mock.

Fundamental problem is that without access to real function/class mock has no way of knowing the order of keyword arguments, that is invocations `call(a=1, b=2)` and `call(b=2, a=1)` look identical to mock, while invocations `call(1, 2)` and `call(2, 1)` do not.

If you wish to generalize mock, you will need to pass a call prototype or a function in lieu of prototype, e.g:

```
amock.afunc.assert_called_with(1, 2, c=3, __prototype__=lambda a=None, b=None, c=None: None)
```

Comment: Perhaps it's time to update the answer, as dictionaries remember order since Python 3.6 and I think that function invocation `**kwargs` also do...